# How to setup PageMethods in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and the project is in .NET 4.5.2
I choose the default template so there are some things like the Master Site and Default.aspx that are in the solution but I have not touched them...

I added a page, `Welcome.aspx` and Can't seem to get the PageMethods to work properly.

**Welcome.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Welcome.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProject.Welcome" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/WelcomeCSS.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
         <form id="WelcomeForm" runat="server">
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

          <div> ... some more html... non <asp:controls>...</div>

          <script type="text/javascript">

             //PageMethods.TestMarker(); // throws exception - PageMethods is undefined.

             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'text',
                contentType: "text",
                url: "Welcome.aspx/TestMarker()",
                data: "{val = adrian}", // parameters for method
                success: function (dt) { alert("HI"+dt); }, //all Ok
                error: function (dt) { alert(dt); } // some error
            }); // doesn't seem to throw an error but C# never gets called
          </script>
       </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

**Welcome.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace HomeVenues
{
    public partial class Welcome : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        protected static void TestMarker(string val)
        {
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

I have the following references:
- system.web.extensions

Q: What am I missing to call my server side code?

Comment: Method should be public and not protected.

Comment: Change your TestMarker Static method Public instead of Protected

Comment: would it be easier to use the PageMethods way?

Comment: I was able to finally use PageMethods but am using a different JQuery... I need the ajax.googleapis however for resize functionality... is there a way to be able to leverage the google scripts in certain areas only?

Comment: Try the sample https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change your Protected WebMethod to Public as follows :

```
[WebMethod]
        Public static void TestMarker(string val)
        {
            return;
        }
```

Change your client side script ajax call as follows :

```
<script>    
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'text',
                    contentType: "text",
                    url: "Welcome.aspx/TestMarker",
                    data: '{ val:"adrian" }', // parameters for method
                    success: function (data) { alert("HI" + data.d); }, //all Ok
                    error: function (data) { alert(data); } // some error
                }); 
</script>
```

***Explanation :- Do remember following points :***

**public**

The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.

**protected**

The type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class or struct, or in a derived class.

**private**

The type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class or struct.

Comment: Tried this and still not able to hit my C#

Comment: fifamaniac04 ,i have just updated the code and update ur code accordingly ... your client side calling have some mistake

Comment: In VS, after the modifications, I get the following in the output window.....Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in System.Web.dll

Comment: This error comes when redirection is there .. multiple times .. we generally use .. Response.End(); to get it reslove ..

Comment: There might be schenerio in your code which would be causing multiple calls to this ajax .. This might be the issue

Comment: probably, I'm trying to call this as part of some user action that can be continuous.... where would I put the Response.end() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try making changes to the below lines of code:

```
public static void TestMarker(string val) //Method should be public
url: "Welcome.aspx/TestMarker", //Dont need enclosing braces
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: JSON.stringify({val:"adrian"}),
```

Comment: Tried this and still not able to hit my C#

Comment: Do you have some redirect defined in the application ?